# Python - Selenium - click specific tab

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, click

I am learning to make use of selenium in python.
Wrote the instructions to open and login to a website. Once in, I need to click the "Reports .." tab, flagged in the attached snapshot.
How do I do that, please,  which element would be the locator/identifier ?

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the text to identify the tab like below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Reports & State')]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath selector in order to select that particular element, that can be done by right click on the flagged element and copy --> copyxpath.

And try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("copied xpath").click()
```

That should work..!